# How do I check which table got updated in an Oracle database when I update any field from the front-end application?

Tags: oracle19c

I have a front-end application which is connected to an oracle database. When I update any field it updates a table in the database. Due to huge size of the application I am not able to find the table name. Is is possible to find the table name which gets update whenever I have updated any field from the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

```
begin dbms_stats.flush_database_monitoring_info; end;

select * from dba_tab_modifications
order by timestamp desc;
```

A FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO is Procedure in DMBS_STATS package. This procedure flush monitoring information for all tables.

```
*_TAB_MODIFICATIONS, *_TAB_STATISTICS and *_IND_STATISTICS views are updated immediately.
```

Monitoring tracks the approximate number of `INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs` for that table and whether the table has been truncated since the last time statistics were gathered. You can access information about changes of tables in the `USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS` view.

These views are populated only for tables with the MONITORING attribute. They are intended for statistics collection over a long period of time.
For performance reasons, the Oracle Database does not populate these views immediately when the actual modifications occur.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.